# keosd not found

Tags: cleos, nodeos, keosd, eosio.cdt

After installing `eosio.cdt`, eos/build/programs/ directory is not found. I cant find `programs` directory inside `build` folder. My intention is to run `keosd` manually. Why `programs` directory is not formed after building and installing cdt?

```
$ keosd
keosd: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to install keosd globally

1. Clone the eos git repository Run eosio_build.sh for building it
2. Run `/root/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod -f /root/opt/mongodb/mongod.conf &` 
            **then**  `export PATH=${HOME}/opt/mongodb/bin:$PATH`
3. `cd eos/build` **Run** `sudo make install`
4. **Run eosio_install.sh shell script or add
   keosd into the system path Try running cleos or keosd anywhere it
   will work**

You have installed keosd but to run it globally you have to add keosd in to the system path.

Answer (score 1):

After cloning eos you will find two shell script files first you run **eosio_build.sh** to install eos and then run **eosio_install.sh**.

**eosio_install** will add all programs of eosio in the system path so you can access eosio programs anywhere regardless of their locations.

**eosio.cdt** is provided only for contract related stuff. So running **keosd** has nothing to do with the smart contracts. **keosd** is only provided for keys management.

Comment: Hmm. I have to run keosd locally in my system for performing Wallet API operations. From where can I get keosd in executable form

Comment: Just do one thing install keosd globally then start keosd and to hit an api for wallet suppose you want to unlock the wallet you can do it via http request for example in curl you can perform that via curl and node i am providing that in different comments please check that.

Comment: CURL
curl -X POST \
  http://127.0.0.1:9999/v1/wallet/unlock \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '["wallet_name","password"]'

Comment: NODE Request
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:9999/v1/wallet/unlock',
  headers: 
   {
     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: 
   [ 'name',
     'password' ],
  json: true };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});

Comment: NODE Request
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:9999/v1/wallet/unlock',
  headers: 
   { 'Postman-Token': '9c5ec802-c344-4fb2-8308-db3a87ba9cff',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: 
   [ 'default',
     'PW5HtWqEs9C8RNXNEmHCyryYLgLotXeV19wyM5geDcNsx77bJtctg' ],
  json: true };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});

Comment: Yes. I know how to deal with wallet APIs. But I don't know from where do I get keosd. How can I install it globally? Should I build the whole EOSIO in my system to run keosd?

Comment: ok let me tell you every step in detail ok Please find my answer.